# How to check for text node of an element in xmltype oracle

Tags: xml, xpath, oracle11g, xquery, xmltype

Using the following query,

```
SELECT *
  FROM sampletable
  WHERE XMLExists('/books/book[@max="30"]' passing XMLCOLUMN);
```

But I want to know , how to check for the plain text content of an element, like

```
SELECT *
  FROM sampletable
  WHERE XMLExists('/books/book="Content"' passing XMLCOLUMN);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if there is a `book` node where the text node equals `Content` (from XPath terms it would return all **book** nodes), do:

```
SELECT *
  FROM sampletable
  WHERE XMLExists('/books/book[.="Content"]';
```

To check if there are `books` nodes where the child node equals `Content` (from XPath terms it would return all **books** nodes), do:

```
SELECT *
  FROM sampletable
  WHERE XMLExists('/books[book="Content"]';
```

Comment: or `/books[book="Content"]` perhaps

Comment: that would return all books elements instead of the book element where the text node has value content

Comment: indeed, but isn't this just a test if some book has the content?

Comment: Yes that's true, but I think it would be good to know that both do a different check/return